# Update-Database: An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a .NET Core web project that requires some User Secrets setup (it is on [GitHub](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Identity/tree/feature/adding-identity-server-4)).

I go and set up my local User Secrets, but then when I run `Update-Database` in Package Manager Console to create the database, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: need to configure key material
>
> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of EF Core when working with User Secrets?